# How to set up a mailing list site manager to bulk send newsletter to customers

Tags: php, sql

I have a mailing list form to sign up to a mailing list and input the details into the database. But now I want an admin section where the user can create an email within the website and send it to all the people that have signed up to the mailing list. How can I do this?

Here is my code for originally creating the mailing list:

```
<?php
// start the session handler
require_once('dbfunction.php');

//connect to database
$conn2 = DB2();

require_once('header.php');

/*
*   should we proceed with the form (if page is not submitted to itself echo the form)
*/
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//detect if we have errors or not
$errors = false;
$error_msg = "Error, please try again";


if (!isset($_POST['full_name']) || $_POST['full_name'] == "") {
 $errors = true;
    echo "<p style='color: red; position: absolute; top:115.5em; right:28em;'>Enter your full name</p>";
}

if (!isset($_POST['email']) || $_POST['email'] == "") {
$errors = true;
    echo "<p style='color: red; position: absolute; top:120.1em; right:25.7em;'>Enter an email</p>";
}

$email = $_POST['email'];

//prepare and set the query and then execute it
$stmt = $conn2->prepare("SELECT COUNT(email) FROM maillist WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count);
while($stmt->fetch()){}

if(!empty($count)){ 
    echo "<p class='red'>Email already registered, please enter an alternative email</p>"; 
}
else

//if we have no errors, do the SQL
if (!$errors) {
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$full_name = ucfirst($full_name);

//insert data
$stmt = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO maillist (billing_name, email) VALUES (?, ?)");

//bind the parameters
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $full_name, $email);

// Execute query
$stmt->execute();

//if the query worked, put out the confirmation message (you can make this look however you want)
if ($stmt) {
  echo "<p class='black'>Thank you for joining out mailing list</p>";

//put out the footer and then stop the rest of the script from running, so we don't display the rest of the form (this is after the form has been submitted)
require_once('footer.php');
exit;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin Control Panel (ACP) aka Backoffice can be written with php easily.
You can create a new file or folder which will follow the next "logic":

> 1.Is the member logged-in and has permissions for ACP? (sessions/cookies)
>
> 2.If not , print the login form and check for his details.
>
> 2.1 If those details exists in your DB `admin` table - create a cookie or session.
>
> 3.If logged in show him the ACP.

There will be an option for the admin to write an email and send it to all of your subscribers. (according to your needs).

So you need to have a simple form with 2 fields: Subject and message (content).
When you submit the form , it will run a php script that will do:

> 1.Get the data of the form (`$_POST['title']` for example)
>
> 2.Fetch all the subscribers from the database with a loop (`while`)
>
> 3.And while fetching them , send them an email with the `mail` function.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel. There are several great services that already do this. They all have an api/functionality that you can use to build your subscriber lists. Plus, you get great reporting and click/link tracking and stats. Creating this functionality yourself would take a lot of effort.

Personally I use use Campaign Monitor - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/. It's rock solid, we've used it to send campaigns of 800,000 emails before :)

Here are the php code examples which enable you to manage list and subscribers:
https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-php

Answer (score 1):

You'd use an external mailing list manager, and send the message to the list address. The external MLM is configured to forward only mail from the web host, and divert everything else to the mailing list administrator. Be sure to test that noone but you can post to the list.

Reinventing the wheel, in PHP nonetheless, is only going to lead to pain, suffering and, in the case of mailing lists, public humiliation. There are just too many things to consider here, for example bounce handling (when an email cannot be delivered, you might want to react and update your database), so stick with an established solution.

Comment: By creating things by yourself you're learning new things and improving development skills. Of course that time & patient is a must.

Comment: In principle, yes, but something that has a lesser impact on customer relations would be a better training ground.